# JCarousel load <li> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, append, jcarousel

I have a JCarousel which scrolls brands available in a store. The brand links, names and images I pull up from another page in the store (the CMS limits me accessing this data differently).

I am pulling the brand data and formatting a `<li>` entry and appending it to the JCarousel. And what ends up happening is the Carousel contains "placeholder `<li>`" and my appended ones in the list but always below view. The syntax of the `<li>` entries looks correct, but I cannot seem to load these in place of JCarousel created placeholders.

And after some research and trial and error, I am stuck so any help is appreciated.

My HTML / JS looks like this:

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="BrandsJCarousel">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/jcarousel.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

    <div class=" jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" style="position: relative; display: block;">
            <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="position: relative;">
                <ul id="brands" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: -850px; width: 1205px;">
                      **// LIST NEEDS TO APPEAR IN HERE**
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="jcarousel-prev jcarousel-prev-horizontal" style="display: block;"></div>
            <div class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal" style="display: block;"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({url: "/brands"}).done(function ( data ) {
                    var html = $(data);
                    var items = $('.SubBrandListGrid li', html);
                    items.each(function() {
                        var link = $('a', this);
                        if(link){
                            var librand = "<li><a href=" + $(link).attr('href') + "><img src=" + $('img', this).attr('src') + " width='60' height='60' alt='" + $(link).text() + "'/></a></li>";
                            $("#brands").append(librand);
                        }                                
                    });                             
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#brands').jcarousel({
                    auto: 10,
                    scroll: 8,
                    wrap: 'circular'
                });
            });
        </script>    

    </div>  
</div>
```

What actually loads into the list (from Chrome Inspect) is this:

```
<ul id="brands" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: -644.80575px; width: 2565px;">
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="1" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="2" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="3" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-4 jcarousel-item-4-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="4" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-5 jcarousel-item-5-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="5" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-6 jcarousel-item-6-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="6" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-7 jcarousel-item-7-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="7" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-8 jcarousel-item-8-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="8" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-9 jcarousel-item-9-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="9" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-10 jcarousel-item-10-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" jcarouselindex="10" style="float: left; list-style: none;"></li>
<li><a href="/brands/ACBEL.html"><img src="/product_images/z/acbel__02930.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="ACBEL"></a></li>
<li><a href="/brands/ACCESS.html"><img src="/product_images/c/access__56651.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="ACCESS"></a></li>
<li><a href="/brands/ACER.html"><img src="/product_images/l/acer__42827.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="ACER"></a></li>
<li><a href="/brands/ACTIVISION.html"><img src="/product_images/p/activision__33939.png" width="60" height="60" alt="ACTIVISION"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `var link = $('a', this);` not this `var link = $('a', $(this));` ??

Comment: Hi Drixon, I do not understand your suggestion. I am not having any issues getting to the brand data, I am having an issue inserting it into the Carousel <ul>. I tried your suggestion though and made no difference, the resulting <li> entries are as per above. Thanks.

Comment: Ok understand now. Have you tried initializing jcarousel after your `items.each(function() {
                        var link = $('a', this);
                        if(link){
                            var librand = "<li><a href=" + $(link).attr('href') + "><img src=" + $('img', this).attr('src') + " width='60' height='60' alt='" + $(link).text() + "'/></a></li>";
                            $("#brands").append(librand);
                        }` Imagine if your <li> is not yet loaded but you already initialized jcarousel , see the picture?

Comment: Hi Drixon, thanks for the reply. What you say makes sense, and I thought I was doing this by having the Script for JCarousel after the Script that creates the <li>. See in my code above, the          "$(document).ready(function() {JQuery('#brands').jcarousel({" piece is after the script that loads the <li> items. Did I understand correctly? Or is the initialization of Carousel something else? This is the first time I use one. Thanks!

Comment: if the jcarousel thave the function to load data <li> to itself than it is much better or the other way you must create the whole `<ul><li></li></ul> tag before initializing $('#brands').jcarousel();`

Comment: Hi Drixson, I just researched what you suggested, but I am still stuck. Can you suggest the code change to try? My sequence first creates the LI then inits JCarousel, so I am not understanding how the second happens before the first!? If there is another way to add to JCarousel I would appreciate an example, as I just looked and cannot seem to find a built in function for this. Thanks

Comment: Hey I just saw this.. `$.ajax({url: "/brands"}).done(function ( data ) {` can you try `$.ajax({ url : '/brands' , success : function(data){ //your script here}  });` I think this can be an issue..

Comment: well im gonna write my script for it ..

Comment: Hi Drixon, thanks for the hints. I found the answer here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_javascript.html... and I jumped the gun! It loaded OK with the brand images but now the buttons seem disabled. How do I post my current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I will do something like this:

Your Carousel:

```
<ul id="brands"></ul>
```

Your script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">    
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
             url: "/brands",
             async:false,
             success : function(data){

             var html = $(data);
             var items = $('.SubBrandListGrid li', html);
             items.each(function() {
               var link = $('a', this);

                 if(link){
                   var librand = "<li><a href=" + $(link).attr('href') + "><img src=" + $('img', this).attr('src') + " width='60' height='60' alt='" + $(link).text() + "'/></a></li>";
                            $("#brands").append(librand);
                 }

             }

            $('#brands').jcarousel({
                auto: 10,
                scroll: 8,
                wrap: 'circular'
            });

         }

        });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey Drixson, rock n roll!!! THANK YOU for your help!!! Only issue (now that I see it load) is that every 9th LI needs to be removed (or not loaded) as the CMS is returning empty data... I think it is because it is formatting the brands page with 8 brands per row?! you can see it here at www.itoutlet.com.au. CHAMPION! thank you for your help!!!!!

Comment: Sorted it. Drixon, thanks again. I learned a lot from your code.

Comment: My pleasure to help you. Cheers!